# Riemann Integrals

Tags: integration, analysis

If I have a function giving different values when rational or irrational, P is a portition of [0,1]. How do i find the upper and lower Riemann integrals to prove if f is Riemann integrable ?

Comment: so if when x was rational it would be 1 and if x where irrational it would be -1 does that make the question easier to answer ?

Comment: Yes. It does. But as a general hint for any such problem, every interval contains both rational and irrational numbers.

Comment: hmmmm ok but if i where to change the scenario and say when x is irrational f(x) = 0 how does that change my approach ??

Comment: It depends on what your approach was, I guess. It shouldn't change things all that much. The only thing that is different is the actual numbers which are involved.

Comment: Did you learn about the darboux defintion?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let us assume that $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(x)=1$ if $x \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{I}$ (here $\mathbb{I}:=\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$). Since $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{I}$ are both dense in $[0,1]$ we have $\displaystyle \sup_{x \in [0,1]}f(x)=1$ and $\displaystyle \inf_{x \in [0,1]}f(x)=0$, so $$\overline{\int_0^1} f(x)dx=1$$ and $$\underline{\int_0^1}f(x)dx=0.$$ In partcular, we see that $f$ is not Riemann-integrable since the value of the upper Darboux-integral does not match the value of the upper Darboux-integral.